# Add border when adding data

Tags: excel, vba

How can I add a border to data added to my sheet?

The code for adding data. The button that loads the `UserForm` is located in the `HOME` sheet. The added data is saved in the `STUDENTS_INFO` sheet.

```vb
Sub add_stud()
    With Worksheets("STUDENTS_INFO")
        r = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        .Cells(r, 3).value = txtBox_LRN.Text
        .Cells(r, 4).value = txtBox_lname.Text
        .Cells(r, 5).value = txtBox_fname.Text
        .Cells(r, 6).value = txtBox_ext.Text
        .Cells(r, 7).value = txtBox_mname.Text
    End With
End Sub
```

I saw this code in this [site](https://excelchamps.com/vba-borders/#:%7E:text=add%20the%20border.-,VBA%20Border%20Property,index%20from%20the%20contants%20avaiable.), but I don't know how to use it.

```
Dim iRange As Range
Dim iCells As Range

Set iRange = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each iCells In iRange
    If Not IsEmpty(iCells) Then
    iCells.BorderAround _
            LineStyle:=xlContinuous, _
            Weight:=xlThin
    End If
Next iCells
```

Comment: Just record a macro painting the border however you want and then use the code generated from that.

Comment: @Ambie Where should I start the recording? In just putting a border to the `STUDENTS_INFO` sheet or should I start in the adding process?

Comment: `LineStyle` to `.LineStyle`. you missed dot.

Comment: View -> Macros -> Record macro, then click Stop Recording when done. Code will be in a module in your editor.

Comment: @Dy.Lee Noted with that. I just copy and paste it, but how can I use that code in VBA? Where should I put it?

Comment: And then record from wherever you like. You can just take the relevant section of code.

Comment: @Ambie alright. I'm going to try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub add_stud()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    With Worksheets("STUDENTS_INFO")
        r = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        .Cells(r, 3).Value = txtBox_LRN.Text
        .Cells(r, 4).Value = txtBox_lname.Text
        .Cells(r, 5).Value = txtBox_fname.Text
        .Cells(r, 6).Value = txtBox_ext.Text
        .Cells(r, 7).Value = txtBox_mname.Text
        Set rngDB = .Range("c" & r).Resize(1, 5)
        With rngDB.Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        
        
    End With
End Sub
```